Condition to have the convexity of the infimum of multi variate polynomial
I consider $f\in\mathbb{R}[x,u]$ a polynomial function where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
I am interested in
$$
g(x)=\inf_{u\in U}\{ f(x,u)\}
$$
Where $U$ is a compact set. I am trying to know if there are conditions that can be imposed on $f$ in order to have the convexity of $g(x)$.
The only condition I thought about was a condition on the degree of the polynomial.
This kind of condition is very natural, but I would like to know if you have any other conditions to suggest that may be weaker ?
Any ideas or hints that I can check by myself is welcome.
Thank you a lot !

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\arginf}{\arg\!\inf}\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}$Let $f$ be defined as $f : \mathcal X \times \mathcal U \to \mathbb R$, where $x \in \mathcal X$ and $u \in \mathcal U$. Then, the domain of $g$ will be the set
$$
\dom g = \left\{x \ \Bigg| \ (x,u^*) \in \text{$\mathcal X \times \mathcal U$ for $u^* = \arginf_{u \in \mathcal U} f(x,u)$}\right\}
$$
However, without any conditions on $\dom g$, it can be non-convex, which renders the function $g$ non-convex. Therefore, it does not matter what conditions you impose on $f$, because $g$ can still be non-convex.

You are right indeed, thank you for the answer !
